# Disable create (sign-up) for tenant in GCP Identity Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-identity

I have enabled multi-tenancy in GCP Identity Platform and unchecked "Enable create (sign-up)" in User Actions section of Identity Platform settings.

I have then implemented example sign-in page by following https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-ui this tutorial.

Specifically I have this snippet in my frontend code:

```
<script>
  var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
  firebase.auth().tenantId = <MY-ONE-AND-ONLY-TENANT-ID>;
  ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', config);
  });
</script>
```

My problem is that it's still possible to create accounts in this tenant scope despite unchecking the "Enable create (sign-up)".

Additionally, if I comment out this line: `firebase.auth().tenantId = <MY-ONE-AND-ONLY-TENANT-ID>;`
I get expected `This operation is restricted to administrators only.` error. Therefore I understand that this setting has effect in general scope of my project.

Question is how do I achieve the same for my tenants if "Settings" page is only available for general scope. It displays `<TENANT-NAME> is a tenant, you can manage <TENANT-NAME> and other tenants in <PROJECT-NAME>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [article](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-web/), when sign-up is disabled in the project settings, it should be mirrored with `adminRestrictedOperation` flag having set to `true` in Firebase. Disabling sign-up in the project settings without setting this to true will not have any effect.

Additionally, you might find this [GitHub article](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#configure-email-provider) useful. You can disable new user sign up with email providers by setting the flag `disableSignUp.status` to `true`. This will display an error message when new users attempt to sign up.

Comment: Unfortunately it is other way round. Article says `Setting this to true without disabling sign-up in the project settings will not have any effect`. And as I said I have it disabled in project settings.

Comment: @JakubNoga Did you find a solution for this problem? I'm experiencing this too, and it's really annoying

Comment: No, it was a hobby project that I dropped. Although recently I was going through docs once again and saw: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users?hl=en#user-actions

`There are situations, however, where you want users to be manually or programmatically created by an administrator, either using the Admin SDK or Firebase console. (...) If you are using multi-tenancy, you will need to make an HTTP request to disable these features on a per-tenant basis.`

Unfortunately the link to the docs gives me 404, maybe that could help you investigate further though.

Comment: The docs here still have a working link https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-manage-users#:~:text=There%20are%20situations%2C%20however%2C%20where,deletion%20by%20an%20end%2Duser.